# Change in TOp Navigation, resulted in "Something went wrong" for Homepage

Tags: sharepoint-server, error

We were making changes for TOP Navigation on SPS 2013 and that resulted the following error while accessing the Intranet - Homepage.

> Sorry, something went wrong  An unexpected error has occurred. 
>   Technical Details
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 15e47c9d-43d0-2048-1429-9438f3f70b47
>
> Date and Time: 17/05/2016 10:19:02 AM

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using correlation Id you can find proper error message from the log.

Comment: @dikesh and others.

a) Checked the Home.aspx running on SPS srv, tried restoring the page to an older version (assumption the page may be corrupted)
 
b) Restarted IIS Virtual directory (refresh the associated Application pools)
 
c) Further analyzing with Microsoft ULS log viewer-
 
As per ULS Viewer
 
UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.   


Followed couple of blogs to troubleshoot the error
 
 - Flushed blobCache using powershell , followed by IISRESET.

Comment: In Addition, 
- We cant perform reset to site definition as that will bring the seattle.master or the homepage to the default page ( may impact the customization we have performed till date)

Comment: Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Site Settings (Top Level) - Navigation - Select Site Collection - Sitename and within that select site navigation.